# jQuery Number field on input not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here are couple of number field with data attribute.I want to get the data attribute on changing the number field value.But it is not working as expected.

Below is the html code

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input data-unit-price="9.99" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input data-unit-price="19.99" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

### And below is my jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';

    var se_ticket_amount = jQuery('.se-ticket-qty');

    se_ticket_amount.on('input', function(e){
        se_ticket_amount.each(function(index,elem){
            var unit_price = jQuery(this).data('unit-price');
            console.log(unit_price);
            console.log(index.val());
        });
    });
});
```

It don't log anything on colsole :/

Comment: You cannot have same id on different elements. Change the id to class

Comment: Did it but not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need `each()`. Try the following way:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';

  var se_ticket_amount = jQuery('.se-ticket-qty');
  se_ticket_amount.on('input', function(e){
    var unit_price = jQuery(this).data('unit-price');
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    console.log('Unit Price:',unit_price);
    console.log('Unit Value:',value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input data-unit-price="9.99" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input data-unit-price="19.99" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should attach an `input` event to the elements, inside the `each` function. See the code below:

```js
jQuery( '.se-ticket-qty' ).each( function() {
  jQuery( this ).on( 'input', function() {
    console.log( jQuery( this ).data( 'unit-price' ) );
    console.log( jQuery( this ).val() )
  } )
} )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input data-unit-price="9.99" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input data-unit-price="19.99" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Mamun, Your answer is more logical.

Answer (score 0):

you can use try the following code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var function_get_input = function(){
        var str = "";
        $("input.se-ticket-qty").each(function(value){
            str+="<span>Input:"+$(this).val()+"</span><br/>";
        });
        
        //show input
        $(".show-input").html(str);
    
    }
    
    //call function_get_input
    
    function_get_input();
    
    
    //event click
    
    $(".change-input").click(function(){
        function_get_input();
    });
    
    
    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="show-input">

</div>
<br/>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input data-unit-price="9.99" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input data-unit-price="19.99" class="se-ticket-qty" type="number" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>

  <tr>
    <td><button class="change-input">Change Input</button>
  </tr>
</table>
```